# Split string using custom separators

Tags: python

I have a string in python:

```
string = "field1|data1||field2|data2||field3|data3"
```

I need to create a dic with this string:

```
dic = {
  "field1": "data1",
  "field2": "data2",
  "field3": "data3"
}
```

How I can make this ?

Comment: Why invent your own serialization of a `dict` when plenty of standard ones (JSON, for example) already exist?

Comment: Shouldn't the separator between `field3` and `data3` be `|` instead of `||`?

Comment: So much inconsistencies

Comment: Looks like you want to split on `||` to get key-value pairs, then split each pair on `|`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dict comprehension with `split`-ing the input first by `||` and then each one by `|`:

```
{k: v for k, v in (i.split('|') for i in text.split('||'))}
```

If you prefer `map`:

```
{k: v for k, v in map(lambda i: i.split('|'), text.split('||'))}
```

**Example:**

```
In [12]: text = "field1|data1||field2|data2||field3|data3"                                                                                                                                                  

In [13]: {k: v for k, v in (i.split('|') for i in text.split('||'))}                                                                                                                                        
Out[13]: {'field1': 'data1', 'field2': 'data2', 'field3': 'data3'}

In [14]: {k: v for k, v in map(lambda i: i.split('|'), text.split('||'))}                                                                                                                                   
Out[14]: {'field1': 'data1', 'field2': 'data2', 'field3': 'data3'}
```

Comment: This is a good place to use the `dict` constructor instead: `dict(i.split('|') for i in text.split('||'))`

Answer (score 1):

You need to split the data after ||. But right field3 & data3 are not in correct order.

```
string = "field1|data1||field2|data2||field3||data3"
dic = {}

data = string.split("||")
for i in range(len(data)):
    elem = data[i]
    if "|" in elem:
        keyVal = elem.split("|")
        dic[keyVal[0]] = keyVal[1]

print(dic)
```

Answer (score 0):

Dict comprehension is the most elegant way

```
string = "field1|data1||field2|data2||field3|data3"
{k:v for k,v in [i.split("|") for i in string.split("||")]}
```

But, it can be done with traditional for loop

```
d={}
for i in string.split(r"||"):
    temp = (i.split("|"))
    d[temp[0]]=temp[1]
```

Comment: Using the `dict` constructor instead would be arguably more elegant: `dict(i.split("|") for i in string.split("||"))`.